# List Category Posts V0.21 upgrade breaks site

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

I just upgraded the List Category Posts plugin from 0.18.3 to 0.21 and my website has failed.

I've determined that the difference causing the failure is that the previous version passes a string parameter to get_posts() while the new version sends the arguments as an array.

The problem is that the default value for post_parent=0 does not seem to have an effect when passed as a string (e.g. "?cat=55&post_parent=0") but it is being applied when the parameter is being passed as an array (e.g. array( 'cat'=>'55', 'post_parent'='0') ).

My posts are post_type='post', for which post_parent should not be applicable. Many of my posts have a post_parent value which is not zero. They were previously batch converted from pages and it appears that the conversion has left the post_parent value with the id of the previous parent page.

As a result of this, all those posts which were previously converted from pages with a parent have disappeared from my category lists.

Can anyone explain why the parameter is being applied as an array and not as a string.

Why is the default value for post_parent 0 fro the plugin, while it is empty for get_posts()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version 0.19, the plugin sends an array to `get_posts` to support custom taxonomy (see [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-list-category-posts-custom-taxonomy-support-and-array-get_posts-call)).

I just uploaded version 0.21.1 with a small bugfix, it doesn't pass the `post_parent` parameter to `get_posts` if you didn't set it. Please give the new version a try and let me know if it's working for you.

Comment: That's fixed it! Thanks for the rapid response.


I had overcome the problem by doing an update in the posts table within MySQL to set the post_parent to 0 for all posts. However I think that your fix is more robust - leaving unused variables to their WP defaults (Null in this case) makes more sense.

Comment: Sorry you had to go through that trouble! Yeah, the plugin still has some sloppy code I've been fixing when I get the time to code on it. Thanks for using it and reporting the bug!